# TR background-image disappears when changing background-image on TD, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, background-image, internet-explorer-7, html-table, tablerow

I have a table with a background-image on my TR. In one of my TD I want to change the background-image dynamic via jQuery.

For changing my TD background-image, I use this code:

```
var dynImage = "imageOfMinMormor.png";
$(".tr .td").css("backgroundImage", "url("+dynImage+")");
```

It works in firefox, safari, chrome and IE 8 <. But in IE7 the background-image disappears on the TR.

Any IE7 hacks?

/Morten

Comment: try adding quotes around the image url ?

Comment: IE handles CSS URLs strangely. Does it work if you use the relative path from your html file rather than from the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

You were passing classnames rather than tag names into the selector:

```
$("tr td").css("backgroundImage", "url("+dynImage+")");
```

Also make sure the image is actually accessible from the location this script is being ran from. You could check your console/network output for any 404's, suggesting the image isn't reachable without modifying its path a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that your jquery selector is invalid for your case. The one you use:

```
$(".tr .td")
```

It selects all elements that have their class attribute set to "td" and their parents have to have their attributes set to "tr" like this:

```
<div class="tr">
    <div class="td">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

And what you want to do is use selector like this:

```
$("tr td")
```

To select all td elements in table rows.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3whmy/4/)